# Max Value in group that fit where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Yes, it is another one of those greatest-n-per-group questions! I have been trying for a few days now trying to work around this problem but to no avail. I have been searching SO too but I don't even know if I am looking in the right place. The most simplified version of the problem as possible is below.

I have 2 tables, one is a many to many and the other has the data.

```
--------a-------    ------------b-----------
| id | version |    | id  | version | external_ref |
|  1 |    1    |    |  1  |    1    |       9      |
|  1 |    2    |    |  1  |    2    |       8      |
|  1 |    3    |    |  1  |    3    |       7      |
|  2 |    1    |    |  2  |    1    |       5      |
|  2 |    2    |    |  2  |    2    |       6      |
       .                          .
       .                          .
       .                          .
```

This is my current (dramatically simplified) query to get the results:

```
SELECT * FROM a 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(Version) FROM a GROUP BY id
    ) j ON a.id = j.id AND a.version = j.version
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND a.version = b.version
WHERE  (b.external_ref = 9 
    OR b.external_ref = 8 (ect)
 ) AND (a.id = 1 OR
       a.id = 2)
```

The problem with this query is that if `external_ref = 7` is not in the where clause then no row is being returned.

If I was looking at entries with only `external_ref` of 8, 9 or 5 then I would like to be able to get the following result

```
| id | version |   data from table a    |
|  1 |    2    | some data from table a |
|  2 |    1    |   some more data       |
```

So how do I get the `MAX(version)` that meets the where clause?

The full query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.`Version`, `t`.`TermID`, `t`.`Definition`, `t`.`Name` 
FROM `term` AS `t`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`Version`) version, `TermID`
    FROM `term`
    GROUP BY `termID`
) jj ON `t`.`TermID` = jj.`TermID` AND `t`.`Version` = jj.`Version`
LEFT JOIN `syllabusin` AS `si` ON `t`.`TermID` = `si`.`TermID` AND `t`.`Version` = `si`.`Version`
LEFT JOIN `synonyms` AS `sy` ON `t`.`TermID` = `sy`.`TermID`
WHERE
  (`si`.`SyllabusID` = 7  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 6  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 5  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 4  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 3  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 2  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 1  
   OR  `si`.`SyllabusID` = 8 )
AND (  `t`.`Name` LIKE '%term%'  
     OR  `t`.`Acronym` LIKE '%term%'  
     OR  `t`.`Definition` LIKE '%term%'  
     OR  `sy`.`Synonym` LIKE '%term%'  )
```

**EDIT:**

To clarify what I want, I want to get the rows from table `a` which are referenced externally (have `external_ref = x`) that have the max version for their id.

Comment: Could you show the results you're trying to get from this data?

Comment: @Barmar question updated to include desired set of results

Comment: How do the `LIKE` conditions figure into this? You need to filter them before or after finding the max version ID?

Comment: Before finding the max version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be it:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, MAX(a.version) AS maxversion
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON a.id = b.id and a.version = b.version
    WHERE b.external_ref IN (9, 8)
    GROUP BY a.id
) AS amax ON a.id = amax.id AND a.version = amax.version
```

It can also be written like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, MAX(a.version) AS maxversion
    FROM a
    JOIN (SELECT *
          FROM b
          WHERE external_ref IN (9, 8)) AS b
    ON a.id = b.id and a.version = b.version
    GROUP BY a.id
) AS amax ON a.id = amax.id AND a.version = amax.version
```

For your more complete query, I think you just have to move all the joins and conditions into the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.`Version`, `t`.`TermID`, `t`.`Definition`, `t`.`Name` 
FROM `term` AS `t`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`Version`) version, `TermID`
    FROM `term` AS t
    JOIN syllabusin AS si ON `t`.`TermID` = jj.`TermID` AND `t`.`Version` = jj.`Version`
    JOIN `synonyms` AS `sy` ON `t`.`TermID` = `sy`.`TermID`
    WHERE
      (`si`.`SyllabusID` IN (7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8)
    AND (  `t`.`Name` LIKE '%term%'  
         OR  `t`.`Acronym` LIKE '%term%'  
         OR  `t`.`Definition` LIKE '%term%'  
         OR  `sy`.`Synonym` LIKE '%term%'  )        
    GROUP BY `termID`
) jj ON `t`.`TermID` = jj.`TermID` AND `t`.`Version` = jj.`Version`
```

It's basically the same logic as the earlier query: You perform a join with all the conditions, and get the max version per ID from that. Then you join with the original table, selecting just the rows that match the ID and max version.

Comment: The problem is that I can't put the where clause into the join due to other joins in the query which are needed (left out for simplicity sake)

Comment: I've shown an alternate version that puts the `WHERE` clause into a subquery, maybe that will work for you? If not, you'll have to show what your real query looks like, I can't guess what's causing your complications.

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to a paste bin with my query, thanks for your help too! :)

Comment: Why make us follow a link, paste it into the question.

Comment: And if you're going to paste a link, make it go to sqlfiddle so we can try it on sample data.

Comment: Why do you use all those `OR` conditions instead of `IN`?

Comment: You need to show what the desired result is with all the additional conditions in the expanded query. It's hard to tell which should be applied before joining and which should be after.

Comment: 1. Because the question was beginning to become bloated

Comment: 2. lesson learnt, will do next time 3. Because I am a beginner just learning.. 4. I think I have explained that in the question already?

Comment: No you haven't. You only gave sample output with no extra conditions. I don't understand how they change the logic.

Comment: Added explaination of desired results to question

Comment: I've put a version of the bigger query into my answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps Barmar, sorry about the problems with the question. I will implement this now as it makes sense!